# Intento de Criba de Eratostenes en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Hola estoy intentando hacer un codigo utlizando el metodo Criba de Eratostenes pero me confundo en la parte de ir multiplicando y eliminar de la lista el numero que no es primo,la profesora dice debemos usar un del o algo asi para eliminar el numero que esta en la lista pero no como es la sintaxis ni nada.

```
n=int(raw_input("Ingrese un numero: "))
lista=[]
i=2
i2=1
cont=0
while i<n:
   lista.append(i)
   i+=1
   while cont <n:
      yu=cont*i
      if yu == lista[]
print lista
```

Esto es lo que llevo y me confundo en como hacer el resto, si pueden ayudarme se los agradeceria mucho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay múltiples formas de resolver este problema. Como mencionaste que se "debe" `usar un del o algo asi` entonces partiendo de esa forma, lo que hice fue generar una lista comenzando del 2 hasta el numero introducido por teclado. Luego se itera con un while mientras el cuadrado del elemento actual sea menor o igual que el numero introducido por teclado. Luego un for recorrerá todos los numeros actuales de la lista y preguntará si ese numero es divisible entre el elemento actual del while. Si es así, entonces se borra de la lista, alterandola.

Cuando el cuadrado del elemento actual (del while) es mayor que el numero introducido por teclado, se finaliza el programa y la lista resultante con puros numeros primos.

```
n = int(raw_input("Ingrese un numero: "))
lista = list(range(2, n+1))

i = 0
while(lista[i]*lista[i] <= n):
    # Mientras el cuadrado del elemento actual sea menor que el ultimo elemento
    for num in lista:
        if num <= lista[i]:
            # Cada iteracion del while hace que el for comience desde el primer elemento. 
            # Esto es para omitir los numeros primos ya encontrados
            continue
        elif num % lista[i] == 0:
            # Si un numero es divisible entre el elemento actual del while
            # de ser asi, entonces eliminarlo de la lista (esto altera la lista)
            lista.remove(num)
        else:
            # Si no es divisible, entonces omitirlo (no hacer nada)
            pass
    i += 1 # Incrementa al siguiente elemento de la lista (que ha sido alterada)

print lista
```

Comment: Detallito: puedes inicializar `lista = list(range(2,n+1))` en vez de la comprensión. Por otro lado, eliminar elementos de una lista mientras se recorre en bucle es en general peligroso y dentro de dos bucles anidados aún más peligroso... Por eso todas las implementaciones que he visto por ahi no usan `del` sino que ponen a `False` los elementos de la lista que no son primos. Pero bueno, lo del `del` rea un requisito del problema (me cuesta comprenderlo) y tu implementación aparentemente funciona...

Comment: Tienes razón @abulafia y en todo momento estuve consciente que es una mala practica alterar una lista sobre la que se está iterando. Si fuera libre de hacerlo como quisiera, pondría una lista donde se acumularían los primos, pero como mencionó algo de "del" supuse que quería eliminar los elementos que no califican directamente de la lista. A menos que fuera de una copia idéntica a la lista inicial y a esa se le van extrayendo los números... como puse, hay varias formas de atacar el problema. Ya modifiqué la generación de la lista inicial.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudaron mucho a entender mejor el ejercicio y aprender mas de python ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
# Versión que imprime por consola el método de eratóstenes.

numero_tope = int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
casillas = {}

# Se construye un diccionario con el universo de números disponibles
for casilla in range(2, numero_tope + 1):
    casillas[casilla] = str(casilla)


def buscarMultiplos(numero_base):
    multiplos = []
    for numero in range(numero_base + 1, numero_tope + 1):
        if(numero % numero_base == 0):
            multiplos.append(numero)
    return multiplos

def mostrarResultado():
    salida = []
    #casillas[3] = "aasd"
    for casilla in casillas:
        if(casillas[casilla].isdigit()):
            salida.append(str(casilla))
        else:
            salida.append("X")
    print(" - ".join(salida))

"""
Pasos desde https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes

1.- Listar los números naturales comprendidos entre 2 hasta el número que se desee.
2.- Se toma el primer número no marcado como número primo.
3.- Se marcan todos los múltiplos del número que se acaba de indicar como primo.
4.- Si el cuadrado del primer número que no ha sido marcado es inferior al numero_tope,
    entonces se repite el segundo paso. Si no, el algoritmo termina, y todos los
    enteros no tachados son declarados primos.
"""
mostrarResultado()

for valor in casillas:
    if(casillas[valor] == "X"):
        continue

    for numero in buscarMultiplos(valor):
        casillas[numero] = "X"
    mostrarResultado()
    if(valor ** 2 > numero_tope):
        break
```