# He desarrollado este algoritmo que calcula los n números primos del rango del número ingresado. ¿Conocen otra forma de hacerlo?

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Algoritmo que determina los n primos de un rango del número ingresado por el usuario.

Comment: Bienvenido, David. Es mejor que el código lo pongas como texto en lugar de una imagen. Hay varios métodos para obtener números primos, pero parece que el enunciado te deja claro el algoritmo que has de usar.¿Preguntas por otros algoritmos o lo que quieres es algún modo de optimizar el que estás usando?

Comment: Hola. Si, me interesan otro tipo. Ya que este solo trabaja hasta el número 5000.

Comment: Una rápida consulta a la wikipedia resolvera tus dudas.

Comment: Las normas de este foro te sugieren buscar otras preguntas similares antes de hacer la tuya. Existe varias preguntas similares a la tuya, por lo que es muy posible que sea cerrada por estar duplicada. Y si buscas otros algoritmos, prueba con la [Criba de Eratóstenes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205988/intento-de-criba-de-eratostenes-en-python).